# DataTable in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a app in win phone 8.1, I need use the DataTable class to pass the data, but this class doesn't exist

The references are fine, the directive using for generate not displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: i dont know about windows phones, Do you have a refference to System.Data ?

Comment: Why do you need it? DataTable isn't available so any code that requires it isn't going to work. There are other (possibly better) ways to read/write data

Comment: Even exist in  WP Libraries

Comment: try adding reference  to System.Data as we do for third party libraries or custom libraries, i mean Refences->Add Reference ...

Comment: Yes, but I had accustomed to DataTable, I'll use Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTable` class is not included in the .NET subset which is supported by Windows Phone 8.1. Compare the 'Version information' at the bottom of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) with the version information of e.g. String ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)).